# How to deselect the selected card/button while mouse hovering another button/card in angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

I have a page where I have many links.
  Like project1, project2, project3..

In onclick of the link,

```
 <a href="http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard;solution=project1;"/>
 <a href="http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard;solution=project2;"/>
 <a href="http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard;solution=project3;"/>
```

So in the next dashboard page, I'am displaying all the projects. So from the first page if I chose "project1", in the next dashboard page(where Im displaying all the projects) Project1 will be highlighted(color change).

```
  <div class="thumbnail"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color':project1Flag == true?'orange':(hlsFlag != true ? '0px solid black':null)}" >
  <img src="/assests/img1"/>Project1
  </div>

   <div class="thumbnail"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color':project2Flag == true?'orange':(hlsFlag != true ? '0px solid black':null)}" (click)="mouse(e);">
  <img src="/assests/img2"/>Project2
  </div>
 <div class="thumbnail"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color':project2Flag == true?'orange':(hlsFlag != true ? '0px solid black':null)}" (click)="mouse(e);">
  <img src="/assests/img3"/>Project3
  </div>
```

In my ts file, based on the routing parameters Im setting up the project flags true or false. Now what is my problem is if I onhover on other projects in dashboard page, highlighted project should not be highlighted.

```
  mouse( e){
    console.log("etype :");
    this.project1Flag = false;
    }
```

So here the flag is setting up false & all, but still the highlight(color change) is applying to the project1. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `click` event and expecting the hover should work. That certainly will not work. Use `(mouseenter)="mouse($event)"` instead.

Comment: I have tried with hover, as it was not working I tried checking in onclick event also. Still the project1 is highlighted. Could you  help me in this?

Comment: Did you try with `mouseenter` or `mourseleave`??

Comment: Try to debug. Is your method being called? Did you check?

Comment: thank you, changing my ngstyle in to ngclass is working for me.